# Scipy detrend puzzle

Tags: python, numpy, scipy

I'm trying to detrend the data INPUT with scipy.detrend.

My code is as follow :

```
OUTPUT=scipy.signal.detrend(INPUT)
```

[image]

Why does the output curve seems off the chart ? It doesn't appear to be correctly detrended. Am i missing something ?

Answer (score 0):

Ironically I found the solution in here : http://www.swharden.com/blog/2010-06-24-detrending-data-in-python-with-numpy/ , but it seems like the author doesn't realize scipy detrend is different than his original solution.

Anyways, I detrended my data with a slightly modified (xrange) code posted in the comments at the page:

```
def detrend(data,degree=10):
    detrended=data.copy()
    for i in xrange(degree,len(data)-degree):
        detrended[i] = data[i] – np.mean(data[i-degree:i+degree])
    return detrended
```

Comment: For completeness, you might post the new output chart, to show what your desired result is.